# Unable to initialize a reference to an interface using Spring

Tags: java, spring, nullpointerexception

I have the following code 
    @Configurable(dependencyCheck = true)
    public class KnowledgeRequestServlet extends HttpServlet {

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("logsDbDao")
private LogsDao dao; ....
```

LogsDao is an interface which has only one method saveRequest() and when I call the same method I get a Null Pointer Exception.
The reference gets initialized when the same code is run on the server.
I see this problem *only when I try to run the code locally on my machine*.I think it has definitely something to do with the Spring Framework I am using. Not only this,none of my references to the Interfaces are getting initialized locally.All of them work fine on the server side.Can some tell me what is messed up.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds rather like Spring isn't getting initialised when you run it on your machine.  Are you starting it up in the same way it runs on the server?

Comment: I am not very sure how to start spring...On the server side I simple deployed the war and it seems to run.On my local machine I am trying to run it thorough Eclipse.
Is there any specific method that needs to be followed?

Comment: How are you trying to run it through Eclipse - you'll need to run it as a WAR using something like WTP on a copy of whatever it is you use to run it on the server

Comment: I thought I fixed it but actually I did not.I run it by Run As -> Run on Server. 
And I have tomcat running locally